# User Defined Functions Are Time Consumer In Queries, What Now?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a sql function that convert Gregorian datetime to Jalali datetime.
I have a table as

```
Id     StartDate       FinishDate        AlarmDate
```

when i excute a  simple query such as this

```
select Id,dbo.Jalali(StartDate) , dbo.Jalali(FinishDate),dbo.Jalali(AlarmDate) from MyTable
```

This query will waste over 2 minute of my time. the table just have 2000 records.

What is the solution?

the function

```
create FUNCTION dbo.MiladiToShamsi
(@dd datetime) 
RETURNS char(10)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @mahs as char(2)
DECLARE @rozs as char(2)
DECLARE @diff As int
DECLARE @i As int
DECLARE @leap As int
DECLARE @roz AS int
DECLARE @mah As int
DECLARE @sal As int


SELECT @roz = 11
SELECT @mah = 10
SELECT @sal = 1358

SELECT @diff = DateDiff("d", cast('1980/01/01' as datetime), @dd) -- leap year

SELECT @i = 1

while @i <= @diff
BEGIN
    SELECT @roz = @roz + 1


    If @mah = 12 And  ((@sal+1) - ((@sal+1)/4)*4) <> 0
            If @roz > 29 BEGIN
                SELECT @roz = 1
                SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End




    If @mah > 12 BEGIN
      SELECT @sal = @sal + 1
      SELECT @mah = 1
   End

    If @mah > 6
            If @roz > 30 BEGIN
                SELECT @roz = 1
                SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End
    if @mah <= 6
            If @roz > 31 BEGIN
                   SELECT @roz = 1
                   SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End 
   SELECT @i = @i + 1

END

if @mah < 10
    SELECT @mahs = '0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@mah)))
else
    SELECT @mahs = LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@mah)))

if @roz < 10
    SELECT @rozs = '0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@roz)))
else
    SELECT @rozs = LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@roz)))

RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@sal))) + '/' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@mahs)) + '/' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@rozs))
END
```

Comment: Please provide the function definition.

Comment: I have heared about clr functions.Is there any solution with them??Are they faster?

Comment: Yes they can be faster for string manipulation. As the function does not do any data access you should use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option, Also I'm not sure exactly what that function is doing but look at getting rid of the procedural code

Comment: I can insert some columns for jalali date to my table and on insert or update i can calculate the jalali date and store it to the columns.

Comment: I would just create a calendar table for this mapping between the 2 date formats and join onto that rather than calling the scalar UDF in your queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your function is based on how many times it loops.  You start your reference day on Jan 1, 1980.  So, to get to current you need to loop approximately 30 * 365 (11,000 times).  I don't know anything about the Jalali calendar, but looking through your code, it seems that every Gregorian calendar date has exactly one representation in the Jalali calendar system.  As such, you can replace your function (that does a lot of loops) with a simple lookup table.

To build the lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [Gregorian] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Jalali] [char](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Gregorian] ASC,
    [Jalali] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Calendar_Jalali_Gregorian] ON [dbo].[Calendar] 
(
    [Jalali] ASC,
    [Gregorian] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

To populate the lookup table with values:

```
Declare @dd datetime

DECLARE @mahs as char(2)
DECLARE @rozs as char(2)
DECLARE @diff As int
DECLARE @i As int
DECLARE @leap As int
DECLARE @roz AS int
DECLARE @mah As int
DECLARE @sal As int


SELECT @roz = 11
SELECT @mah = 10
SELECT @sal = 1358

SELECT @diff = DateDiff("d", cast('1980/01/01' as datetime), @dd) -- leap year

SELECT @i = 1

Set @dd = '19800101'
while @dd <= '22000101'
BEGIN
    SELECT @roz = @roz + 1


    If @mah = 12 And  ((@sal+1) - ((@sal+1)/4)*4) <> 0
            If @roz > 29 BEGIN
                SELECT @roz = 1
                SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End




    If @mah > 12 BEGIN
      SELECT @sal = @sal + 1
      SELECT @mah = 1
   End

    If @mah > 6
            If @roz > 30 BEGIN
                SELECT @roz = 1
                SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End
    if @mah <= 6
            If @roz > 31 BEGIN
                   SELECT @roz = 1
                   SELECT @mah = @mah + 1
            End 

    if @mah < 10
        SELECT @mahs = '0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@mah)))
    else
        SELECT @mahs = LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@mah)))

    if @roz < 10
        SELECT @rozs = '0' + LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@roz)))
    else
        SELECT @rozs = LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@roz)))

    Insert Into Calendar(Gregorian, Jalali)
    Select @dd, LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@sal))) + '/' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@mahs)) + '/' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@rozs))

   SELECT @dd = DATEADD(day, 1, @dd)

END
```

Now you can simplify your function to this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MiladiToShamsi
(@dd datetime) 
RETURNS char(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    Return (Select Jalali 
            From   dbo.Calendar 
            Where  Gregorian = DateAdd(Day, DateDiff(Day, 0, @dd), 0)
            )
END
```

Now when you run the query, it should perform better.  However, when you have a user defined function that performs table access like this one, performance may still suffer because SQL Server will access table once for each function call.  Instead, it would be better to not use the function at all.  Now that there is a lookup table, you can simply join to it (3 times) to get all the conversions, like this:

```
select Id,
       StartDate.Jalali As StartDate,
       FinishDate.Jalali As FinishDate,
       AlarmDate.Jalali As AlarmDate
From   MyTable
       Inner Join Calendar As StartDate
          On MyTable.StartDate = StartDate.Gregorian
       Inner Join Calendar As FinishDate
          On MyTable.FinishDate = FinishDate.Greogorian
       Inner Join Calendar As AlarmDate
          On MyTable.AlarmDate = AlarmDate.Gregorian
```

You said, in your original post, that it took more than 2 minutes to get your results.  If you decide to follow my advice here, I would be curious to know how long it takes with the method I describe.  I'm absolutely sure it will be faster than your current method.